# Using IFTTT to sync my Alexa ToDo and Shopping list with iOS reminders

Tags: ios, icloud, reminders

So I have managed to setup an IFTTT applet to copy new todo's and Shopping list items from my Alexa to my Apple iOS reminders.  When I tried to create an option to remove them from Alexa (Todoist) when they were deleted the options to delete are not in the Alexa end of the app.

[image]

Comment: IFTTT doesn't support that. Try contacting them to ask if they'll add deleting Alexa reminders

Comment: Did you ask them if they can do this?